# Iptables: Reasons for choosing pre-up/up/post-up rsp. pre-down/down/post-down

Tags: linux, iptables

Setting up iptables rules, what are the specific reasons for pre-up/up/post-up rsp. pre-down/down/post-down?

E.g setting Default Policies in pre-up and explicit rules in up/post-up?

In my understanding, if I only want to setup e.g iptables-save < ..., it doesn't matter. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is that the firewall is up *before* any network traffic can happen on a certain interface or all interfaces and that the firewall is up *as long* as networking is possible, meaning as long as the interface(s) is up.

Comment: hek2mgl thank you very much for quick response!

Comment: Does it mean, that you have apply rules at pre-up because of applying at /etc/network/interfaces->up or /etc/network/if-up.d can be a security risk. Would there be a delay applying rules at up-time between interface being up and the time rules would be active?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying.